# Not able to switch to iframe using Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, iframe, automated-tests

I am trying to click on SIGN IN link which is placed inside the iframe with class attribute "modalIframe". I have been trying for the past two days to find a solution for this but not able to. Any help would be really appreciated.

Code as below

```
public class Datereader
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\Madankumar\\Desktop\\Gecko Driver\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.redbus.in/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class='icon-down icon ich dib']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("signInLink")).click();    
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        WebElement iframeElement=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='modalIframe']"));
        driver.switchTo().frame(iframeElement);
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("sign in")).click();


    }
}
```

On running the code I am getting below error:

> JavaScript warning: https://cdn-jp.gsecondscreen.com/static/tac.min.js, line 3: unreachable code after return statement

Comment: can you share full error log

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use Below code for handling iframe.**

```
WebElement iframe = driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe"));
driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);           //Move inside to the frame.
WebElement body = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body"));
body.click();
driver.findElement(By.linkText("sign in")).click();
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();       //Move outside to the frame.
```

Answer (score 0):

While exploring the HTML and trying out different XPATHs to find the element, it is observed that there are `3 elements` present with the same element attributes. so, to made it unique, build the relative XPATH starting from `GooglePlus Signup` element, then find the `sign in` link relative to that.

try the following code:

```
    WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.redbus.in/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class='icon-down icon ich dib']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("signInLink")).click();    
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    WebElement iframeElement=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='modalIframe']"));
    driver.switchTo().frame(iframeElement);
    WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='googlePlusBtn1']/following-sibling::div/span/a"));
    System.out.println("element " + elem);
    Thread.sleep(1000); // without this line, observed that click is not resulting in displaying the Login form, though selenium did not throw any error (means, click did not result in Login form). you can alternatively try out with WebDriverWait. this is trial and error. if it is working for you without sleep, you can remove this line.
    elem.click();
    Thread.sleep(5000); // can remove sleep. kept only for visual confirmaiton to check whether Login form is displayed, as there are no steps further after this in the code.
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. You should explain the reason the OPs code wasn't working and how yours addresses that. Also is there no way you can avoid Thread.sleep()? It's generally considered pretty bad practice unless absolutely necessary

Comment: @ExoticChimp, edited the answer to explain things that I have done to solve the issue. thanks for good suggestion.

Comment: Thanks @Naveen. The code worked with WebDriverWait while removing Thread.sleep(). Also with respect to SIGN IN element I did try with linkText as well but that even did not work out.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Yes, linkText may not return the right element as there are 3 such elements with the same text. hence derived the XPATH from GooglePlusSignin, which exactly finds the required element.