# Selecting nested iframe with selenium webdriver Chrome and C#

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have a frame and inside that clicking a button opens an iFrame. my frame selection seems to work and i know my XPath is good (because it works in chrome) but my test always fails with

OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException: Timed out after 5 seconds ---> OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//em[.='Job Selector']"}

attached are some images that show HTML and sources.

in my code I'm using:

```
 // wait for menu frame to appear
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.XPath("//frame[@id='menu']")));


        // do a bunch of stuff

        driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.XPath("//frame[@id='master']")));




        // Add to running jobs: open iFrame
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_cphMain_cmdAdd")).Click();



        //driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent(); tried with and without this
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.XPath("//iframe[@name='JobWindow']")));



        // wait for SelectJob Window to appear tried several elements
        //wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("RadWindowWrapper_ctl00_cphMain_JobWindow")));
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//em[.='Job Selector']")));
```

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally got this to work:

```
 wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.XPath("//iframe[@name='JobWindow']")));
            IWebElement body = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body"));
            body.Click();


            // wait for SelectJob Window to appear
             IWebElement SaveButton = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("cmdSave")));  
            SaveButton.Click();
```

Without the body.click, no luck

Props to Jainish: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41500131/1667188