# How to keep dropdown active and click on submenu available under iframes in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Requirement: Click on submenu from Actions dropdown which looks like below and each element is in different iframes

Selenium 3.141

Actions > Menu > Submenu > click on submenu item

Actions - iframe1 > Menu - iframe2 > Submenu - iframe3

All these frames are inside one another iframe3 is inside iframe2 and iframe2 is inside iframe1

Dropdown opens when I click on 'Actions' and closes when I try to click on other and hence script fails with an exception element not found to click

````
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@title, 'Actions')]")).click();
switchToFrame("listHidden");
driver.findElement(By.id("PMCProjectCreateMenu")).click();
switchToFrame("submenu");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(label,'Create New...')]"));

or

//in below case how to switch to iframes
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
WebElement actionMenu= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@title, 'Actions')]"));
action.moveToElement(actionMenu).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("PMCProjectCreateMenu"))).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(label,'Create New...')]"))).click().build().perform();```

Expected : To navigate through actions > menu > submenu and click on submenu
Actual: Clicks on actions and fails to continue
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of your calls to switchToFrame(), try using WebDriverWait and the expected condition frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt, so that the driver waits enough time for the new inner iframe to display ...

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("listHidden");
```

there's also some talk that you need to click on the body after the switch, but I've not tested that.
(found this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45222495/4321213)